# See POST Multipart Form Data Request

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.5, multipartform-data, wireshark

I'm trying to submit a multipart form through a C# and a VB.NET console application, but how do I see what it actually looks like? I've seen on some forums that you can see what it looks like through WireShark. I need to match it with the API documentation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try Telerik fiddler it is much simpler than WIreShark.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's super old but I wanted to answer in case someone else needs it.

```
        Dim EncodedContent As New MultipartFormDataContent
        EncodedContent.Add(New StringContent("0"), "Hello World!")
        Debug.Print(EncodedContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)'<Prints MultipartForm to console
```